# Creating Workflow in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-workflow-manager

I have just started with Workflow Manager in ArcGIS Pro, and have created a Workflow Database, in which I can create new jobs.

However, I just see the three sample job templates (data edits, landbase updates and web edits), and was wondering how I can create my own job template / workflow.

Do I still need the old Workflow Manager desktop application, or can I do everything from within Pro?

I read the 'getting started' document but that's about running existing workflows (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/workflow-manager/get-started-with-workflow-manager.htm)

Comment: Have you tried expanding or scrolling that "Create Jobs" window/ the Jobs Template Gallery? From the documentation, it looks like there may be more templates available. If not, I would think that Esri still needs to work to make this as complete as ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

You actually still need desktop application Workflow Manager Administrator to create new Jobs (and new Workflows). Migration of these functions from ArcMap environment to ArcGIS Pro is still in the process and probably will take lot of time.